# Can not create the application private directory in Android API 23 (Google Nexus 6p)

Tags: android

I have tried to create the the application private directory in android api 23 (Google Nexus 6p) device but it gives the exception like : ENOENT (no such file or directory) but below that means below API 6 it is working fine and created folder successfully. Any one can help to solve this problem? I am using below method to create private directory

```
private void createDirectory() {
        try {
           String s = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator
                    + "data" + File.separator + getPackageName();
            File dir = new File(s);
            if (dir.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Directory created");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Directory is not created");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("FILE", "Error Package name not found ", e);
        }
    }
```

Also Use android manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If it is permission error then If I create my application package folder manually in "/storage/0/Android/com.test" this folder then other files in that directory can create successfully. But I can not create "/storage/0/Android/com.test" programmatically in Android API level 23.

I read the Android M new runtime permission guide lines but I can not find any directory created level permission.

Comment: @ArturSzymański : I read the Android M new runtime permission guide lines but I can not find any directory created level permission.

Comment: Your sample code do not use them currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options :

1/ You don't need to target 23 Sdk Version. You can just downgrade your targetSdkVersion to 22. Your app will behave as before, the user will be prompted to grant permissions at installation time . It should be noted that an Android 6 user will have the ability to deny permission later in the app settings, resulting in bad behavior of the app.

2/ You need to target 23 Sdk Version. In that case you need to prompt Android 6 user to grant permission. Here an Activity example (partial code):

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

private static final int EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Prompt Android 6 user if permission is not yet granted
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            createDirectory();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    createDirectory();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this,  "Read/Write External Storage Not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
    }

    private void createDirectory() {
    // unchanged
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Permission management has changed since Android 6.0 :
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Try to manually enable Storage permission for your app in Settins/Apps/YourApp/Permissions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kkhi.png)

Comment: Any permission related to write external storage ? If there then how can I ask from the user ? Please provide me a sample

Comment: Take a look to my new post above